# Duvida sobre cifra de César

Tags: c, criptografia

O problema é que eu preciso parar de imprimir quando ele chegar no último digito do vetor só que não sei como fazer, e também como vou imprimir depois do z, porque do jeito que eu fiz ele não imprimi ? ( Sou iniciante então se puder explicar como funciona agradeço )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    char cifra[50];

    printf("\nInforme um texto: ");
    gets(cifra);

    for(int i=0; i<**50**; i++){
        if(cifra[i]>'z'){
            cifra[i]='a';
            printf("%c",cifra[i]+1);
        }else{
            printf("%c",cifra[i]+3);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja se entendeu o meu codigo alguma duvida avise. 
PS: Os sinais de pontuação irão ser cifrados, se não quiser adicione outra condição.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

char cifra[50];
int tam;

printf("\nInforme um texto: ");
fgets(cifra,50,stdin); // Não é recomendado usar gets,então eu useifgets que faz o mesmo
                       // no 1º parametro está a string para onde vai o texto
                       // o 2º parametro o tamanho da string
                       // o 3º é o standard input ou seja o teclado

tam = strlen(cifra); // variável para saber o comprimento da string digitada

for(int i=0; i<tam; i++)
{
    if(cifra[i] == 'z')
        cifra[i] = 'a';
    else
        if(cifra[i] == ' ' || cifra[i] == '\n') // Caso seja um espaço ou uma quebra de linha ele 
                                                // apenas imprime não avança 3 
            printf("%c",cifra[i]);
        else
            printf("%c",cifra[i] + 3);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Vlw, eu tinha feito sozinho menos a parte do z, entendi teu código e ajudou muito vlw por responder cara !